# How to call a dynamic mixin in SASS?

Tags: sass

It is possible to call dynamic mixin name from within class?

## Something like:

```scss
@mixin mixin_test {
   color: red;
   position: relative;
}

$mixin_name: mixin_test;
.test {
   @include $mixin_name;
}
```

### Because I have a List structure of class names and mixin names, and I need to @include them (key is class name, value is the name of mixin).

```scss
$helper-declarations--mixins: (
    full-parent: _full-parent,
    full-of-parent: _full-of-parent
);
```

It is necessary for me, because I dynamically building the classes like normal:

```scss
// .full-parent > .full-of-parent
@include generate_breakpoints_helpers($helper-declarations--mixins);
```

or next time with some rules for some breakpoints, like:

```scss
@include generate_breakpoints_helpers($helper-declarations--mixins, (
    'medium': (
        'full-parent',
    ),
    'large': (
        'full-parent',
        'full-of-parent'
    ),
    'no-tablet': (
        'full-parent'
    )
));
```

Comment: This is more a job for Javascript. Remember that SASS is compiled into CSS and that is what is used on your site. SASS cannot react to conditions after being compiled

Comment: Hi Brad, thanx for your reply, but the point is more about the SASS can't include dynamic name of the mixin, like @include $mixin_name; :/